# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, plotly

I´m trying to make an interactive graph from a time series using plotly in Python and I get this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(256)

Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import plotly
import chart_studio

chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username='****',                                              
                                  api_key='*****')

import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

def parser2(x):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime( x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')#
    except:
        return 0

filename = r'AT_2018_10last.csv'
datafolder = Path('C:\HiWi Rodriguez\AT 2018\Last Value')
pathfile = datafolder / filename
ts = read_csv(pathfile, header=0,  parse_dates=[0], index_col=0 ,  date_parser=parser2)#, dtype = dtypes)
ts.columns = ['A']
ts.plot()

AT = go.Scatter(x=ts.index, y=ts.A)

layout = go.Layout(title='Ambient Temperature', xaxis=dict(title='Date'),
                   yaxis=dict(title='[°C]'))

fig = go.Figure(data=AT, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, sharing='public')
```

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\utils.py", line 37, in basic_auth
    password = password.encode("latin1")

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: if isinstance(username, str):
        username = username.encode("latin1")

    if isinstance(password, str):
        password = password.encode("latin1")

    return "Basic " + to_native_ascii_string(
        b64encode(b":".join((username, password))).strip()
    )

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like `chart_studio` only allows characters from the [extended ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/) to be used for the username and password.

According to your error message the wrong character seems to be in your password.
You can use the following code to check your password:

```
YOUR_PASSWORD = "your_p♥$$w0rd!_here"

for character in YOUR_PASSWORD:
    code_point = ord(character)

    if code_point < 256:
        print(f"    ok: {character} ({code_point})")
    else:
        print(f"not ok: {character} ({code_point})")
```

As you can see in the example output the character `♥` has a code point of `9829` and would therefore be the problem because it's not in the range of 255:

> ok: y    (121)
>   ok: o    (111)
>   ok: u    (117)
>   ok: r    (114)
>   ok: _    (95)
>   ok: p    (112)
>   not ok: ♥    (9829)
>   ok: $    (36)
>   ok: $    (36)
>   ok: w    (119)
>   ok: 0    (48)
>   ok: r    (114)
>   ok: d    (100)
>   ok: !    (33)
>   ok: _    (95)
>   ok: h    (104)
>   ok: e    (101)
>   ok: r    (114)
>   ok: e    (101)